# How to export the Html Tables data into PDF using Jspdf

Tags: jquery, html, jspdf

How do I export the tables in HTML page to PDF. I have done some sample data but  I am unable to load the HTML table list into PDF, Please can any one help me in loading the Tables into PDF.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>html2canvas example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>    

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                var specialElementHandlers = {
                    '#editor': function(element, renderer) { return true; }
                };

                $('#cmd').click(function() {
                    var doc = new jsPDF();

                    doc.fromHTML($('#target').html(), 15, 15, {
                        'width': 170,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                    });

                    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
                });  
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="target">
        <div id="content">
            <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

            <a class="upload">Upload to Imgur</a>    
            <h2>this is <b>bold</b> <span style="color:red">red</span></h2>

            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Header 1</th>
                    <th>Header 2</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
                    <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                    <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y2b7Q/327/

Answer (score 15):

A good option is [AutoTable(a Table plugin for jsPDF)](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable), it  includes themes, rowspan, colspan, extract data from html, works with json, you can also personalize your headers and make them horizontals. [Here](https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable) is a demo.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There is a [tablePlugin for jspdf](https://github.com/Prashanth-Nelli/jsPdfTablePlugin) it expects array of objects and displays that data as a table. You can style the text and headers with little changes in the code. It is open source and also has examples for you to get started with.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do it.

jsPDF does not support exporting images and tables in **fromHTML** method. in jsPDF v0.9.0 rc2

Comment: Yes, the answer is 'true', but it is not ***correct*** to answer this question. OP is asking for help to export to pdf, and has shown an attempt.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example I think that will help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/min.js"></script>
<script src="js/pdf.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
         var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

   $('#cmd').click(function () {

        var table = tableToJson($('#StudentInfoListTable').get(0))
        var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt', 'a4', true);
        doc.cellInitialize();
        $.each(table, function (i, row){
            console.debug(row);
            $.each(row, function (j, cell){
                doc.cell(10, 50,120, 50, cell, i);  // 2nd parameter=top margin,1st=left margin 3rd=row cell width 4th=Row height
            })
        })


        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
    function tableToJson(table) {
    var data = [];

    // first row needs to be headers
    var headers = [];
    for (var i=0; i<table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
        headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi,'');
    }


    // go through cells
    for (var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++) {

        var tableRow = table.rows[i];
        var rowData = {};

        for (var j=0; j<tableRow.cells.length; j++) {

            rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;

        }

        data.push(rowData);
    }       

    return data;
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="table">
<table id="StudentInfoListTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>    
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Track</th>
                        <th>S.S.C Roll</th>
                        <th>S.S.C Division</th>
                        <th>H.S.C Roll</th>
                        <th>H.S.C Division</th>
                        <th>District</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td>alimon  </td>
                            <td>Email</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2222</td>
                            <td>as</td>
                            <td>3333</td>
                            <td>dd</td>
                            <td>33</td>
                        </tr>               
                </tbody>
            </table>
<button id="cmd">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

"[How to properly use jsPDF library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858954/how-to-properly-use-jspdf-library)" might give you a little more of what you need.  The table won't render correctly ([no css, per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460035/jspdf-cant-get-any-styling-to-work)), but you could do some parsing of the html table with jquery and manually style it yourself.

Another option would be to use screenshots of the HTML with [HTML2Canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) or [Casper.js](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureselector).

**EDIT**

Here's a basic example using the jspdf cell plugin.  It uses jquery and the `tableToJson()` function from [HTML Table to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271856/html-table-to-json).

Be sure to include the Deflate lib (two js files) and `jspdf.plugin.cell.js`.

```
var table = tableToJson($('#table-id').get(0))
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);
doc.cellInitialize();
$.each(table, function (i, row){
  $.each(row, function (j, cell){
    doc.cell(10, 200, 100, 20, cell, i);
  })
})
doc.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

**Just follow these steps i can assure pdf file will be generated**

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <title>Exporting table data to pdf Example</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/from_html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/split_text_to_size.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cell.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/FileSaver.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#exportpdf").click(function() {
                var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'ledger');
                // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
                // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
                source = $('#yourTableIdName')[0];

                // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
                // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
                // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
                // (class, of compound) at this time.
                specialElementHandlers = {
                    // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
                    '#bypassme' : function(element, renderer) {
                        // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                        return true
                    }
                };
                margins = {
                    top : 80,
                    bottom : 60,
                    left : 60,
                    width : 522
                };
                // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
                // 'inches' in this case
                pdf.fromHTML(source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
                margins.left, // x coord
                margins.top, { // y coord
                    'width' : margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                    'elementHandlers' : specialElementHandlers
                },

                function(dispose) {
                    // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
                    //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                    pdf.save('fileNameOfGeneretedPdf.pdf');
                }, margins);
            });

        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="yourTableIdName">
        <table style="width: 1020px;font-size: 12px;" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr align="left">
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>


            <tbody>

                <tr align="left">
                    <td>India</td>
                    <td>Telangana</td>
                    <td>Nirmal</td>
                </tr>
<tr align="left">
                    <td>India</td>
                    <td>Telangana</td>
                    <td>Nirmal</td>
                </tr><tr align="left">
                    <td>India</td>
                    <td>Telangana</td>
                    <td>Nirmal</td>
                </tr><tr align="left">
                    <td>India</td>
                    <td>Telangana</td>
                    <td>Nirmal</td>
                </tr><tr align="left">
                    <td>India</td>
                    <td>Telangana</td>
                    <td>Nirmal</td>
                </tr><tr align="left">
                    <td>India</td>
                    <td>Telangana</td>
                    <td>Nirmal</td>
                </tr><tr align="left">
                    <td>India</td>
                    <td>Telangana</td>
                    <td>Nirmal</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table></div>

        <input type="button" id="exportpdf" value="Download PDF">


    </body>

    </html>
```

Output:

Html file output:
[image: html output]

Pdf file output:
[image: pdf output]

Answer (score 2):

Try to put

```
doc.fromHTML($('#target').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
```

instead of

```
doc.fromHTML($('#target').html(), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I Used **Datatable JS plugin** for my purpose of exporting an html table data into various formats. With my experience it was very quick, easy to use and configure with minimal coding.

Below is a sample jquery call using datatable plugin, `#example` is your table id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Please find the complete example in below datatable reference link :

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

This is how it looks after configuration( from reference site) : 
[image]

You need to have following library references in your html ( some can be found in the above reference link)

```
jquery-1.12.3.js
jquery.dataTables.min.js
dataTables.buttons.min.js
jszip.min.js
pdfmake.min.js
vfs_fonts.js
buttons.html5.min.js
```