# How can I apply styles like color, table CSS for jsPDF?

Tags: jspdf

I'm new to using jsPDF, am able to generate normal PDF fine, but when am trying to apply external CSS or normal style background color its does not have any effect.

My JSP includes are:

```
<script  src="Javascript/external/jspdf.js"></script>
<script  src="Javascript/external/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script> 
<script  src="Javascript/external/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>               
<script  src="Javascript/external/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script src="Javascript/external/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

I am using the script below to generate HTML.

Comment: Where is that script you mention?

Comment: jsPDF doesn't seem to support CSS unfortunately - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20518296/3768252)

Answer (score 36):

Set Font Size

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(22);
doc.text(20, 20, 'This is a title');
```

Set Font Type

```
 doc.setFont("times");
 doc.setFontType("italic");
 doc.text(20, 40, 'This is times italic.');
```

Set font Color

```
 doc.setTextColor(255,0,0);
 doc.text(20, 40, 'This is red.');
```

Comment: think of text color in jspdf like a paintbrush. Set color, write that color, then reset color to default after to continue