# jspdf fromHTML table style

Tags: jspdf, fromhtml

I am using jspdf to convert a webpage into a pdf document and I have the from_html plugin included. It converts all the tables in my document and everything is fine except I would really like to change the way to tables look. They all have a dark grey head and the text is bold and too large. I can't work out how to change them.

Things I have tried:

- Setting the color and size inside the td tag
- Changing the doc.table_font_size to a smaller number before doc.save
- Searching through the js files to try to find where they are set

Can anyone tell me what I haven't tried or if this is even possible please? All of the demos of tables made with jspdf seem to look the same as mine but I would really like to change it.

Thank you!

James

Answer (score 0):

You have tried:

- Setting the color and size inside the td tag

Unfortunately jsPDF doesn't seem to support CSS - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460035/jspdf-cant-get-any-styling-to-work/20518296#20518296).

- Changing the doc.table_font_size to a smaller number before doc.save

Have you tried using `doc.setFontSize(size)`?

- Searching through the js files to try to find where they are set

Here is the [debug file](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js) - much handier to search through.

I know this isn't a direct solution to what you're trying to do, but I hope it helps a little bit - I just started learning how to use jsPDF too, but I'm building tables from scratch rather than trying to export them from the HTML.

Comment: Thank you. In the end I have also adding the tables manually which did allow me to change the Drawcolor etc. It works OK and together with images etc I have ended up with an entire Walker which deals with lots of elements.  Happy to share code if you need it! Thanks again!