# javascript code to execute onclick function but only resolve within a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible.. to have my javascript, example as in below; to simply continue to execute with my click function but the changes are *only* reflective in a new window - while current page (non-new window does not change via the JS) is this possible?

```
   $('.download-pdf').click(function() {

   $(this).attr('target', '_blank');

    notChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parent();
    notChecked.hide();
    yesChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parent();

    $.each(yesChecked, function( index, el ) {
      $(el).show().html(texts[$(el).attr('id')]);
    });
```

Comment: You want the click to make changes in a page that isn't loaded yet?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Well, I really want the click to only resolve changes in dynamically generated pdf it is generated ie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211409/dynamic-pdf-from-user-input-not-reflective-on-current-page-only-in-the-pdf but as I cannot find a solution for this, this is the hack I'm coming up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `postMessage` API which is perfectly described in [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18004937/1041122). You can do this only, if the new window has the same origin.

Probably you'd need to wait some time for the new frame to be fully loaded.