# How to export multiple tables to single pdf

Tags: jquery

I have three tables with different columns. I want to export those three tables to single *pdf*.

```
<table>
 <thead><th>test header</th></thead>
 <tbody><td>test</td></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **jspdf** Yo can export multiple tables to single pdf

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ud8jkvf/8786/)

JS need to add

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
     <table><thead><th>test header</th></thead>
 <tbody><td>test</td></tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

Script

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Krn Rajput

Comment: By using this export is working but the table is not exporting properly in pdf

Comment: what do you mean ?
table is not exporting properly in pdf ?
please explain what you want and how should be display

Comment: I have 3 tables with data and I want export those to pdf

Comment: Please share your html code in jsfiddle.
so someone can help you

Comment: As i know jsPDF is not working with CSS
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460035/jspdf-cant-get-any-styling-to-work

Answer (score -3):

Simple way is that,

1. COPY and PASTE tables content from Browser to MS-Word
2. Do proper alignment of the content
3. Save this .doc file by selecting 'SAVE As Type' - PDF(*.pdf)
4. there you will get required pdf file.