# HTML not transferring to PDF using JSPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am trying to use jspdf to print div element into pdf. However its giving me margin error.I am not sure where I am going wrong. I have added margins but its coming in line bey line and is missing CSS which I have written. As requested I have added the HTML code as well.

Below is the js I have written

```
margins = {
  top: 70,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 30,
  width: 550
};

 function genIdCards(){
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    pdf.setFontSize(18);
    pdf.fromHTML(document.getElementById('id-card'), 
        margins.left, // x coord
        margins.top,
        {
          // y coord
          width: margins.width// max width of content on PDF
        },function(dispose) {
          pdf.save('Test.pdf');
        }, 
        margins);
};
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="genIdCards()">Generate PDF</button>
```

CSS

```
.id-card {
        height: auto;
        float: left;
        background: #fff;
        width: 500px;
        margin: 40px;
        border: 1px solid #7c0000;
    }

.apeejay-school {
    height: 97px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #7c0000;
}

.logo {
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.apeejay-school-content {
    width: 75%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

below is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

<head>
    <?php include_once("../header.php"); ?>

</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->

<body class="page-header-fixed page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo page-container-bg-solid page-content-white">

    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <?php include_once("../navbar.php"); ?>
        <!-- BEGIN HEADER & CONTENT DIVIDER -->
        <div class="clearfix">
        </div>
        <!-- END HEADER & CONTENT DIVIDER -->
        <!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
        <div class="page-container">
            <?php include_once("../side_bar.php"); ?>
            <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
            <div class="page-content-wrapper">
                <!-- BEGIN CONTENT BODY -->
                <div class="page-content">
                    <div class="page-bar">
                        <ul class="page-breadcrumb">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Student Management</a>
                                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>ID Cards</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php include_once("../lcode.php");?>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label> Academic Year*</label>
                            <select id="acadyear" name="acadyr" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">--Please select--</option>
                                        <?php fetch_acad_yr($conn);
                                        ?>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label> Class</label>
                            <select id="acadclass" name="cclass" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">--Please select--</option>
                                        <?php fetch_class($conn);
                                        ?>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>Section</label>
                            <select id="section" name="csec" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">--Please select--</option>
                                        <?php fetch_section($conn);
                                        ?>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">

                            <button id="liststudents" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="process" style="margin-top: 6%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Display List</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <button id="genId" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  onclick="genIdCards()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Generate Id Cards</button>
                    <br><br><br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="portlet light">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="liststu" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
                                                <th>Student ID</th>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Class and Section</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>


                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                            <div id="id-card" class="id-card">

                <div class="apeejay-school">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="apeejay School"></div>

                    <div class="apeejay-school-content">
                        <div class="apeejay-school-txt">
                            Apeejay School
                        </div>
                        <div class="school-location text-center">
                            college Road , Charkhi Dadri-127306
                        </div>
                        <div class="ph-fax text-center">Ph.:01250-222172, Fax : 01250-225172</div>
                        <div class="email-apeejay-school text-center">Email : skool.ms.chkd@ap.edu</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="student-information">
                    <div class="student-details">
                        <div name="idName" class="name">Atul Kumar</div>
                        <div class="student-details-txt">
                            <div class="category">F / Name :</div>
                            <div name="idFname" class="category-detail">O P Sharma</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="student-details-txt">
                            <div class="category">Admin . No.:</div>
                            <div name="idAno" class="category-detail">001</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="student-details-txt">
                            <div class="category">Class :</div>
                            <div name="idCls" class="category-detail"> VI</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="student-details-txt">
                            <div class="category">House :</div>
                            <div name="idHouse" class="category-detail">Nayak</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="student-details-txt">
                            <div class="category">Address :</div>
                            <div name="idAdd" class="category-detail">25/2 , Krishana Colony, <br>Bhiwani</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="student-details-txt">
                            <div class="category">Phone No :</div>
                            <div name="idPhnum" class="category-detail">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="student-bio">
                        <div name="idSession" class="session">2009-2010</div>
                        <div class="student-pic"><img id="<?php echo ASSETIMG_PATH ?>" class="student-pic" name="stuimg" alt="Student"></div>
                        <div class="sinature"></div>
                        <div class="principal">Principal Sign</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--
                            <div class="portlet light">
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END QUICK SIDEBAR -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END CONTAINER -->
    <?php include_once("../footer_text.php"); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="idhtml">

    </div>
    <div class="quick-nav-overlay"></div>
    <?php include_once("../footer.php"); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=ASSET_PATH?>assets/staff_js/validation.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=ASSET_PATH?>assets/staff_js/stumgmt/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=ASSET_PATH?>assets/staff_js/stumgmt/icard.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: from where the `margins` are coming?

Comment: @Javascript_Lover forget to add the complete script have edited the question

Comment: Hi @JaGaurav that's fine, but whenever posting the question, create the 
 stack snippet https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ I will do now

Comment: @JaGaurav refer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460035/jspdf-cant-get-any-styling-to-work

Answer (score 0):

Move out the `pdf.save()` from `function(dispose){}`, below is the working one

```js
margins = {
  top: 70,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 30,
  width: 550
};

function genIdCards() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  pdf.setFontSize(18);
  pdf.fromHTML(document.getElementById('id-card'),
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, {
      // y coord
      width: margins.width // max width of content on PDF
    },
    function(dispose) {
      pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    },
    margins);


};
```

```css
#id-card {
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #7c0000;
}

.apeejay-school {
  height: 97px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #7c0000;
}

.logo {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.apeejay-school-content {
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<div id='id-card'>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="test.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class=".apeejay-school">
    <div class="apeejay-school-content">
      Some content for testSome content for testSome content for testSome content for testSome content for testSome content for testSome content for test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="genIdCards()">Generate PDF</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote for you the working solution. You do not have to change the position of `pdf.save('Test.pdf');`

```js
var margins =
{
    top: 70,
    left: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 40,
    width: 550
};

function genIdCards()
{
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    //pdf.setFontSize(18);
    pdf.fromHTML(document.getElementById('idhtml'),
        margins.left, // x coord
        margins.top,
        {
            // y coord
            width: margins.width // max width of content on PDF
        },
        function(dispose)
        {
            //headerFooterFormatting(pdf, pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages());
            pdf.save('Test.pdf');            
        },
        margins
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul id="idhtml">
 <li>Some text 1</li>
 <li>Some text 2</li>
 <li>Some text 3</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="genIdCards()">Generate PDF</button>
```

**Edit:**

After your question changing I have tried to find new solution for you. Unfortunatelly jsPDF does not support the CSS. Only simple HTML will be supported. But I wrote the new solution for you without CSS:

Please execute **[this snippet](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBebbB)** on codepen.io and see the PDF.

Comment: Thanks for this. Its printing the data but it is missing the CSS which I have written

Comment: @JaGaurav, if you give me your HTML then I can use your CSS.

Comment: Have added the HTML

Comment: @JaGaurav, I wrote the new solution for you - see my answer on the bottom.

Comment: @JaGaurav, thanking on StackOverflow is done by upvoting and by answer accepting. If you are satisfied with my answer below, please mark it as accepted on the left side from my answer and / or upvote it.