# Can I use window.print() to export a page to PDF automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, kendo-ui, export

I'm searching for methods to export my HTML div to a PDF format. My current lead is to use `window.print()` to send the page to print, making the destination 'Save as PDF', and continuing from there. It's not perfect, and I'm here to ask if it's possible to write code to automate the part where a user would click 'Save as PDF' and also the part where they name there file.

Ideally, all that happens is a user clicks a button to export, the 'Save as PDF' click happens behind the scenes, and the file is automatically named `report.pdf`. Is this possible to codify?

I am also open to any suggestions on other ways to export my HTML into a PDF format, however I **cannot** use either of the following libraries to aid me in this:

- `jsPDF` does NOT support CSS on its own, and therefore is out of the question.
- I am aware that jsPDF can be used in conjunction with `rasterizeHTML` or `html2canvas`, however both of these work by taking a screenshot of the page and appending said screenshot to the file. This means the page is unsearchable using `CTRL+F`, which is one of the use cases of my project.

Another option I have is to use the [Xportability](https://github.com/Xportability/css-to-pdf) library, but as of right now I haven't been able to pass any stylesheets into the PDF generation call. Here is the code at fault that generates a PDF with all of my recorded data, but doesn't style with the provided CSS:

```
<script id="finalReport" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <h3 class="report-header">stub title</h3>
    <table class="report-table">
        <tr>
            <td>Report ID:</td>
            <td>stub</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>

<style>
  .report-header {
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>

<script id="main" type="text/javascript">
    function generateReport() {
        return xepOnline.Formatter.Format("finalReport", {
            render: 'download', pageWidth: '216mm', pageHeight: '279mm'
        });
    }
</script>
```

How do I pass in the style sheet? I can manually add the style to every single element and it works like that, but that would be awful.

Comment: Where did you get this impression that "jsPDF does NOT support CSS on its own, and therefore is out of the question."?

Comment: pretty much every single StackOverflow post about jsPDF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946275/exporting-pdf-with-jspdf-not-rendering-css

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460035/jspdf-cant-get-any-styling-to-work/46544213

Comment: http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html; https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: Xportability is described as producing a PDF 'from a hosted PDF rendering service'. I find it quite a bad idea to have user-data processed externally without the user being aware of the risks it involves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kendo UI `pdf-export`component to download the particular `div` elements.

Sample Code:

```
$(".export-pdf").click(function() {
        // Convert the DOM element to a drawing using kendo.drawing.drawDOM
        kendo.drawing.drawDOM($(".content-wrapper"))
        .then(function(group) {
            // Render the result as a PDF file
            return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group, {
                paperSize: "auto",
                margin: { left: "1cm", top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" }
            });
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            // Save the PDF file
            kendo.saveAs({
                dataURI: data,
                fileName: "HR-Dashboard.pdf",
                proxyURL: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
            });
        });
    });
```

for `fileName` you can give whatever the filename you want and it will save the file with that file name.

**URL:** [PDF Export / Document Export](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pdf-export/index)

Comment: Will drawDom keep the page in a text format or will it draw it to a canvas?

Comment: how to call the content of another view using kendo jqeury-ui

Answer (score -1):

Once you get to the print page you can easy tell the document to print as a pdf by selecting the destination button

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking if I can automate this process and have that all done by the computer automatically rather than by the user.

Comment: Not all and sundry can read.