# jsPDF Big table, headers overlap in second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, svg, jspdf

I'm using `jsPDF` and `svg_to_pdf` to export both an SVG and a table to a PDF. This is my code:

```
function svg_to_pdf(svg, callback) {

console.log("svgtopdf.js");
svgAsDataUri(svg, {}, function(svg_uri) {
var image = document.createElement('img');

image.src = svg_uri;
image.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', 'a4', true);
  var dataUrl;

  source = $('#datos_alumnos')[0];
  specialElementHandlers = {
      '#bypassme' : function(element, renderer){
          return true;
      }
  };

  margins = {
            top: 40,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 270
        };


  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 500, 263);


  doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    40,
    270, {
        'width': 550,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function(dispose){
        //doc.save('SVG.pdf');
    }
    , margins);

callback(doc);
}
});
}
```

The result is a PDF with the image at the top and the table next. The problem comes when it enters the second page as the headers of the table overlap with the first row and it looks like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfRX3.png

Is it possible to remove the headers on the second page?

Comment: Could you include an example table?

Comment: The table is generated on PHP and it looks like this [link](http://i.imgur.com/aoy2leM.png), theres no issue at the start of the table on the PDF.

Comment: This [link](http://i.imgur.com/8yrGUpy.png) is the first page.

Comment: [This post might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797821/rendering-tables-with-jspdf?rq=1)

Comment: I tried using `autotable`, the problem was that im converting both the `SVG` and the table from `svg_to_pdf` and I can't call functions from `autotable` from `svg_to_pdf`.

Comment: My best option would be to use [this](http://w3lessons.info/2015/07/13/export-html-table-to-excel-csv-json-pdf-png-using-jquery/) to convert the table to png, then append it to your svg.pdf file. Besides that it does not look like there are many other options.

Comment: I will check that out, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I've found a possible solution for this, if you are using this script for jsPDF

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.debug.js

you can download it, and modify line 5201 to have a negative value, for example;

```
    this.margins.top = -50;
```

With this there is no header on the second page of the PDF.

I've tried playing around with the code without much success, if I find a better way I will update this answer (don't know if I'm allowed to do that).

Answer (score 0):

When you draw table, just use:

```
startY: doc.internal.getNumberOfPages() > 1 ? doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 20 : 200,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding css classes like -
 thead { 
    display: table-header-group 
  }
  tfoot { 
    display: table-row-group 
  }
  tr { 
    page-break-inside: avoid 
  }

Comment: Explain it please!

Answer (score 0):

I did a work around, instead of adding header to all the pages, add header separately to the first page. From the second page add it as footer.