# Download table as PNG using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, download

I want to download a html table as a PNG image, I found a way using JQuery to extract the table as an Image but it opens in a new tab and don't automatically download I must use right click then save as image to be able to download it.

is there any way to make it download automatically?

This is the JQuery used to export as PNG Image

```
$('#preview-table').tableExport({type:'png',escape:'false'});
```

Comment: I this solution might work take a look
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31087577/2377278

Comment: As of now there is no way to export the table to an image using Jquery. There is no `tableExport()` function as the part of the Jquery library. That must be some other plugin. Please clarify.

Comment: @Raw N He uses this plugin here [tableExport.jquery.plugin](https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin) and it actually does exactly this. It saves tables to images and other file formats.

Answer (score 7):

In order to do this and force the browser to download the data as file, you have to change the mime type from `data:image` to `data:application/octet-stream`. You need to create your own `html2canvas` conversion and handle the `onrendered` event manually. Then inside `onrendered` event handler function, you store the canvas data url. After that, use regular expression to change the base64 data mime type from `data:image` to `data:application/octet-stream`. Then you can use `window.open(uri)` to force the browser to download the file, but if you want to specify a filename, you need to create a anchor link element and set the download attribute with the filename you desire:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="preview-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button id="export">Table Export</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="tableExport.jquery.plugin/html2canvas.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#export').on('click', function() {
    html2canvas($('#preview-table'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {                                      

            var saveAs = function(uri, filename) {
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
                    document.body.appendChild(link); // Firefox requires the link to be in the body
                    link.download = filename;
                    link.href = uri;
                    link.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(link); // remove the link when done
                } else {
                    location.replace(uri);
                }
            };

            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
                uri = img.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');

            saveAs(uri, 'tableExport.png');
        }
    }); 
});

</script>
```

Here you can find a working example: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/tableExport/

[Check Rob W's answer on **Browser/HTML Force download of image from src=“data:image/jpeg;base64…”**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473992/1889685) and [Reddy's answer on **Save file Javascript with file name [duplicate]**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26361461/1889685)