# Export HTML table to pdf using jspdf

Tags: jspdf

I need to export the HTML table to pdf file using jspdf. I tried the below code but it displays the blank/empty output in pdf file. Any suggestions or sample code for this would be helpful.
`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function demo1() {
        $(function () {
            var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
         $('#cmd').click(function () {
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                doc.fromHTML($('#htmlTableId').html(), 15, 15, {
                    'width': 170,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                });
                doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
            });  
        }); 
    }
</script>
`
```

Answer (score 49):

Here is working example:

in head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function demoFromHTML() {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
            // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
            // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
            source = $('#customers')[0];

            // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
            // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
            // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
            // (class, of compound) at this time.
            specialElementHandlers = {
                // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
                '#bypassme': function(element, renderer) {
                    // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                    return true
                }
            };
            margins = {
                top: 80,
                bottom: 60,
                left: 40,
                width: 522
            };
            // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
            // 'inches' in this case
            pdf.fromHTML(
                    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
                    margins.left, // x coord
                    margins.top, {// y coord
                        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                    },
            function(dispose) {
                // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
                //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                pdf.save('Test.pdf');
            }
            , margins);
        }
    </script>
```

and table:

```
<div id="customers">
        <table id="tab_customers" class="table table-striped" >
            <colgroup>
                <col width="20%">
                <col width="20%">
                <col width="20%">
                <col width="20%">
            </colgroup>
            <thead>         
                <tr class='warning'>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Population</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Chinna</td>
                    <td>1,363,480,000</td>
                    <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                    <td>19.1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>India</td>
                    <td>1,241,900,000</td>
                    <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                    <td>17.4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>United States</td>
                    <td>317,746,000</td>
                    <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                    <td>4.44</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Indonesia</td>
                    <td>249,866,000</td>
                    <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                    <td>3.49</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brazil</td>
                    <td>201,032,714</td>
                    <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                    <td>2.81</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table> 
    </div>
```

and button to run:

```
<button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML()">PDF</button>
```

and working example online:

[tabel to pdf jspdf](http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/7806/)

or try this: [HTML Table Export](http://ngiriraj.com/pages/htmltable_export/demo.php)

Comment: The content in the cell is overflowing any way to prevent that?

Comment: @szakalq If I add arabic letters to your jsfiddle code, these arabic letters are not shown in pdf. Do you have solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Works great except, any HTML tag inside is not shown. For example if I have a `UL` inside a cell it just shown text on different lines. If I have a text underlined or bold, it doesn't show it.

Comment: how can i apply css on the pdf exported table

Comment: this code only exports first 4 columns, how to increase number of columns to be exported.

Comment: I just copied the function and fired it for a svg, it did nothing. Any thing I didn't considered? @szakalq

Comment: I copied this verbatim and I get a pdf with "undefined".  If I use var source = $('#table')[0]; it does nothing.  I have to change it to var source = $('#table').first();  This is where I get undefined.

Comment: I tried the given solution, but it exports only 1 side, means prints only left side. Can anyone help me out, how can i resolve this issue ? am i missed anything ?

Comment: Heads up in the JS fiddle in Firefox I get ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined

Comment: Jsfiddle not working even in chrome: `ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined`

Comment: This is working great for me, but I would like to do some customizations like font size and having the header row wrap text.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use the [jsPDF-AutoTable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) plugin. You can check out a demo [here](https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable) that uses the following code.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
autoTable(doc, "#basic-table");
doc.save("table.pdf");
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this package as it seemed quite capable. However, how do I program the button to execute the function to save the table?

Comment: I get a 404-error when trying to access that page I'm afraid

Comment: My bad, check this link instead [examples/simple.html](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/examples/simple.html)

Comment: Thanks. However, my table is dynamically generated and in HTML-format (I have no experience from JS I'm afraid)

Comment: Try to look the from html example. If you cant get it to work, feel free to post a new stackoverflow question and link to it here.

Comment: TypeError: doc.autoTableHtmlToJson is not a function

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: doc.autoTable is not a function

Answer (score 2):

Use `get(0)` instead of `html()`.  In other words, replace

```
doc.fromHTML($('#htmlTableId').html(), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
```

with

```
doc.fromHTML($('#htmlTableId').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 1):

We can separate out section of which we need to convert in PDF

For example, if table is in class "**pdf-table-wrap**"

After this, we need to call **html2canvas** function combined with **jsPDF**

following is sample code

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [580, 630]);
html2canvas($(".pdf-table-wrap")[0], {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
        var width = canvas.width;
        var height = canvas.clientHeight;
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 20, 20, (width - 10), (height));

    }
});
setTimeout(function() {
    //jsPDF code to save file
    pdf.save('sample.pdf');
}, 0);
```

**Complete tutorial** is given here http://freakyjolly.com/create-multipage-html-pdf-jspdf-html2canvas/