# HTML to PDF - jspdf ignoring second column in case of table

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I have a `div` which contains some data and a `table`. The problem I'm facing now is that `jspdf` is ignoring the second column of the table and only printing the first column of each row. The following is the HTML and JS

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <p id="bypassme">Some text</p>
    <p>Some more text</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>Second</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Third</td>
            <td>Fourth</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    var html = $('#myDiv').html();      
    var specialElementHandlers = {
         '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
             return true;
          }
    };
    doc.fromHTML(html,10,10, {
            'width': 500,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
         });
    doc.save("Test.pdf");
</script>
```

#### What is seen on page:

```
Some text
Some more text
+-------+--------+
| First | Second |
+-------+--------+
| Third | Fourth |
+-------+--------+
```

#### Actual output

```
Some more text
First
Third
```

#### Expected output

```
Some more text
First     Second
Third     Fourth
```

Comment: You already have all in other topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035858/export-html-table-to-pdf-using-jspdf

Comment: I beg to differ. That only works when the data in question contains only a table. In my case, it's a combination of table and some other HTML tags