# How do I convert with Angular: HTML into PDF

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I'm using Angular and I wanna convert a table from html into pdf, this is my code in component.ts:

```
downloadPDF() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    const specialElememtHandlers = {
        '#editor'(element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    doc.fromHTML(this.content.nativeElement.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
        width: 190,
        elementHandlers: specialElememtHandlers
    });
    doc.save('test.pdf');
}
```

and my html code is:

```
<button (click)="downloadPDF()">Save as PDF</button>
```

I actually can download a pdf, but it is completely white.

Comment: can you update your table? Is it dynamic or static?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export HTML table to pdf using jspdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035858/export-html-table-to-pdf-using-jspdf)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly Install this package

> npm install jspdf

And to install html2canvas package.

> npm install html2canvas

Import it into our component using the import statement.

```
import * as jspdf from 'jspdf';  
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

in your TS code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef ,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';  
import * as jspdf from 'jspdf';  
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';  

@Component({  
  selector: 'app-htmltopdf',  
  templateUrl: './htmltopdf.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./htmltopdf.component.css']  
})  
export class HtmltopdfComponent{  
  public captureScreen()  
  {  
    var data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');  //Id of the table
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {  
      // Few necessary setting options  
      let imgWidth = 208;   
      let pageHeight = 295;    
      let imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
      let heightLeft = imgHeight;  

      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
      let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
      let position = 0;  
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)  
      pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF   
    });  
  }  
}
```

Comment: what if it's a div with variable size?

Comment: @UlisesCT are you still facing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the library 'PrintJS' for converting html templates to pdf.
https://printjs.crabbly.com/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly install this package

```sh
npm install jspdf
npm install html2canvas@1.0.0-alpha.12 //working with this html2canvas version.
```

Import it into our component using the import statement(app.component.ts).

```js
import * as jspdf from 'jspdf';  
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

Add app.component.html

```html
<div class="abc" id="content">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <button (click)="Screen()">make pdf</button>
</div>
```

Add app.component.ts

```js
Screen()
{  
    var data = document.getElementById('content');  
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {  
        // Few necessary setting options  
        var imgWidth = 208;   
        var pageHeight = 295;    
        var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
        var heightLeft = imgHeight;  

        const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
        let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
        var position = 0;  
        pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)  
        pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF   
    });  
}
```

Comment: thank you. You know how to send the document instead of download?

Answer (score 0):

Here is
[StackBlitz Demo Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-html-to-pdf-example-answer)

Hope this will help