# convert json data to pdf using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to export JSON data to pdf with out using any third party plugin.I am having data in Json and need to display data in pdf table structure using JQuery. Please let me know if its possible.

Here is sample JSON

```
 jsonResult.Products[         
       {PRODUCT_ID: 123, PRODUCT_NUMBER: "00022", PRODUCT_NAME: "HONDA", PRODUCT_TYPE: "VEHICLE "},
       {PRODUCT_ID: 783, PRODUCT_NUMBER: "08412394", PRODUCT_NAME: "HONDA", PRODUCT_TYPE: "MOTOR "}.....]
```

Code snippet using jS PDF-autotable

```
<script src="~/Scripts/JsPDF-Autotable.js"></script>

 $("#btnExportPDF").click(function () {

        let table = document.createElement('table');
        table.setAttribute("id", "pdfTable");
        let thead = document.createElement('thead');
        let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        let thead_tr = document.createElement('tr');

        let sample = dataResult.Cases[0];

        let columns = [];
        let columnData = [];

        for (let column in sample) columns.push(column);

        for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            let th = document.createElement('th');
            th.innerText = columns[i];
            thead_tr.appendChild(th);
        }
        thead.appendChild(thead_tr);
        for (let i = 0; i < dataResult.Cases.length; i++) {
            let tr = document.createElement('tr');
            let product = dataResult.Cases[i];
            for (let column = 0; column < columns.length; column++) {
                let td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerText = product[columns[column]];
                columnData.push(product[columns[column]]);
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
        }
        table.appendChild(thead);
        table.appendChild(tbody);
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
        doc.autoTable(columns, columnData)
        doc.save("table.pdf");
    });
```

I tried to export to pdf using jspdf autotable  and I am getting below error

```
JsPDF-Autotable.js:1538 Use of deprecated autoTable initiation
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code, including the code which is currently working to export the html table to pdf.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Added code snippet for converting toPDF

Comment: That code doesn't convert anything to PDF. It presents a dialog where, if the user has a Print to PDF capability, they can print the page to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's definitely possible.

The process is very simple:

1. Prepare your JSON data
2. Create a table element filled with your data
3. Export table with [JSPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

**Creating the table**

```
let table = document.createElement('table');
let thead = document.createElement('thead');
let tbody = document.createElement('tbody ');
let thead_tr = document.createElement('tr');

let sample = jsonResult.Products[0];

let columns = [];

for (let column in sample) columns.push(column);

for (let i = 0; i<columns.length;i++){
    let th = document.createElement('th');
    th.innerText = columns[i];
    thead_tr.appendChild(th);
}       
thead.appendChild(thead_tr);
for (let i = 0; i<jsonResult.Products.length;i++){
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    let product = jsonResult.Products[i];
    for (let column = 0; column < columns.length; column++){
        let td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerText = product[columns[column]];
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
table.appendChild(thead);
table.appendChild(tbody);
document.body.appendChild(table); // Now this is your table which you are going to export
```

[Follow this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035858/export-html-table-to-pdf-using-jspdf) answer/guide to export the HTML table with JSPDF

Comment: From the OP: "with out [sic] using any third party plugin"...

Comment: Well, @HereticMonkey, it *is* possible if you cut out the relevant code bits from the jsPDF library. But who wants to do that?!? Constantin showed a way of at least doing the job without having any clientside PDF-creating capabilities otherwise.

Comment: @Constantin Teo- I tried with the code provided and using JsPDF.The data is not aligned properly and pages are empty after first page has alignment issue.As I am having 15 columns and 3k rows of data.How can i fit those into pdf using JsPDF.I tried with JSPDF.Autotable which is giving me error : "failed to execute 'queryselector' on 'document' "

Comment: @AMDI please update your question with relevant material that provides enough data for us to comprehend your issue.

Comment: @ConstantinTeo - I have updated code whic i am using JSPDF-AutoTable

Comment: @AMDI use `pdf.fromHTML()` and pass the `table` variable, amongst with the other required parameters (see the link in the answer)

Comment: @ConstantinTeo - I tried using pdf.fromHTML() method but as i said earlier the page is not able to accommodate 15 columns and pages are showing as blank and data is shifting to right.Please let me know how to accommodate 15 columns with data of 3k rows

Comment: When you say the "page" is not able to accommodate your data, which page are you referring to? Does the issue happen on DOM or on the JSPDF library?

Comment: @ConstantinTeo - I am referring to pdf pages. when i exported to pdf using jsPDF. Please let me know if there are properties of jspdf to accommodate 15 columns with data gets wrapped.

Comment: @AMDI please update your question by graphically exposing your issue.

Comment: @ConstantinTeo- I have updated code in separate question with some code snippet and images https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61843197/facing-issue-while-exporting-to-pdf-with-more-columns.  Please take a look and let me know if you can suggest.