# make a button to download a table in format pdf lanscape

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi friends, I want to help a group to make the table without using the pen and paper. I created the dynamic timetable with javascript, html and css. There is one  thing that I found difficult, it is to make a button that allows to download the table in a pdf format in lanscape, which I found difficult, please help me!

here is the link of the code in github :  https://github.com/zahiraaa/timetable

```js
const timetable = document.getElementById("timetable");

const days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
const hours = ["7H", "13H", "20H"];

// Create table headers for days
const daysHeaderRow = document.createElement("tr");
const daysHeaderCell = document.createElement("th");
daysHeaderCell.innerHTML = "Days";
daysHeaderRow.appendChild(daysHeaderCell);
days.forEach(day => {
  const dayHeaderCell = document.createElement("th");
  dayHeaderCell.innerHTML = day;
  dayHeaderCell.colSpan = 3;
  daysHeaderRow.appendChild(dayHeaderCell);
});
timetable.appendChild(daysHeaderRow);

// Create table headers for hours
const hoursHeaderRow = document.createElement("tr");
const hoursHeaderCell = document.createElement("th");
hoursHeaderCell.innerHTML = "Hours";
hoursHeaderRow.appendChild(hoursHeaderCell);
for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    const hourHeaderCell = document.createElement("th");
    hourHeaderCell.innerHTML = hours[j];
    hoursHeaderRow.appendChild(hourHeaderCell);
  }
}
timetable.appendChild(hoursHeaderRow);

// Create row for Mina
const names = ["Khalfi","Redouani", "Daki", "Hamma", "Saadane", "Boughanem", "El Ansari","Badilou","Raoui", "Chouiba", "Dahmane", "Achdad", "Bouryal", "Ettouri", "Saadouni"];
for (let name of names) {
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  const nameCell = document.createElement("td");
  nameCell.innerHTML = name;
  row.appendChild(nameCell);
  for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      const cell = document.createElement("td");
      const select = document.createElement("select");
      select.classList.add("cell");
      const options = [" ", "CP", "ME", "CL", "CE", "R"];
      options.forEach(option => {
        const optionElement = document.createElement("option");
        optionElement.value = option;
        optionElement.innerHTML = option;
        select.appendChild(optionElement);
      });
      cell.appendChild(select);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
  }
  timetable.appendChild(row);
}




function exportCSV() {
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#timetable tr");
    var csvData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var rowData = [];
        var cells = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
            const select = cells[j].querySelector("select");
            if(select){
                rowData.push(select.value);
            }else{
                rowData.push(cells[j].innerText);
            }
        }
        csvData.push(rowData);
    }
    var csv = Papa.unparse(csvData);
    var csvData = new Blob([csv], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
    var csvURL =  null;
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        csvURL = navigator.msSaveBlob(csvData, 'timetable.csv');
    } else {
        csvURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
    }
    var tempLink = document.createElement('a');
    tempLink.href = csvURL;
    tempLink.setAttribute('download', 'timetable.csv');
    tempLink.click();

    // Convert the CSV data to a PDF and download it
    
var pdf = new jsPDF('l','mm','a4');
pdf.addPage();
pdf.text(csv, 10, 10);
pdf.save('timetable.pdf');
}
```

```css
#timetable th {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
padding: 8px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #006699; /* bleu foncé /
}
#timetable tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #E6E6FA; / lavande */
}

/* Mise en page globale */
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Style de la barre de navigation */
nav {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Style de la section principale */
main {
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Style des titres */
h1, h2, h3 {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Style des paragraphes */
p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Style des images */
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="timetable">

 <body>
 <tr>
      <td>

        <link href="table.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="table.js"></script>
        <form action="table.php" method="post">

    </td>

<tr>

<button onclick="exportCSV()">Export CSV</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="exportPDF()">Export PDF</button>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.77/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.77/pdfmake.min.vfs.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.77/vfs_fonts.js"></script>


<button id="download-pdf-button">Télécharger en PDF</button>

<script>
    var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download-pdf-button");
    downloadButton.addEventListener("click", downloadPDFWithPDFMake);
</script>




   
 </body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export HTML table to pdf using jspdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035858/export-html-table-to-pdf-using-jspdf)

Comment: UNfortunately, I tried jspdf, and it does not work

Comment: Please post that code and any details about how it did not work.

Comment: Yogi, the code is here in github : https://github.com/zahiraaa/timetable

Comment: The html page has multiple mistakes that may prevent it from working correctly.  The structure of the html table is incorrect and also the button id (there is an error in the console).

Comment: ok Yogi, I am trying to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Nice idea

The csv heading would *perhaps* be better as `Days,,Monday,,,Tuesday,,,Wednesday,,,Thursday,,,Friday,,,Saturday,,,Sunday,` since csv does not carry merged fields.

It works well printed landscape by browser but for jsPDF you need to apply it again at the time of add page

`pdf.addPage();`

[defaults to `a4,p`](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/jsPDF.html#addPage) so

```
pdf.addPage('a4','l');
```

should work.

For custom shapes and full syntax visibility use

```
pdf.addPage([841.89, 595.28],"landscape");
```